# Error occurs passing (broken) image to model

Tags: python, pandas, image, skip

While passing a folder of images to a ML-script, I'll receive an error, maybe caused by a broken image:

> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001C3BB0AAEA0>

My code:

```
for files in Files:
        if files.endswith(".jpg"):
            image_name = files
            image_check = image.load_img(image_name, target_size=(1200,1600))  
            images = image.img_to_array(image_check)
            images = np.expand_dims(images, axis=0)
            prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(images), axis=-1)
```

The script stops running, whenever this error occurs. Is it possible to just skip the according file and move over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would be doing it the following way:

```
for files in Files:
    if files.endswith(".jpg"):
        try:
            image_name = files
            image_check = image.load_img(image_name, target_size=(1200,1600))  
            images = image.img_to_array(image_check)
            images = np.expand_dims(images, axis=0)
            prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(images), axis=-1)
        except:
            # NHI means 'Need Human Intervention'
            prediction = 'NHI'
```

The predictions with `NHI` value will be considered for RCA (root cause analysis).

Comment: bare except is bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except

Comment: Using this code, my script does not work properly anymore. "prediction" can have the values 0 or 1 due to the employed model. With "try" and "except" it is not getting any values anymore...